# Android emulator won't work on mac Yosemite

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have installed eclipse and android SDK and HAMX(1.1.1)on Mac Yosmite,

When I create the Device and start it I get this:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'test'
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Size: 69206016
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 4224
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 1024
Label: 
Blocks: 16896
Block groups: 1
Reserved block group size: 7
```

Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
  emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

and the device start but it's just black nothing is showing. Does any body have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something wrong with the gui, so here is what I did:

In the emulator options check use Host Gpu, then click ok, refresh and start

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, just close it, delete and create a new one. Try if it help you.